# Oozie action not running in fork join

Tags: hive, workflow, action, oozie, fork-join

I am trying to run two action in parallel using the fork join in oozie. Here is my workflow :

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" name="hive-wf">
    <start to="forking"/>
    <fork name="forking">
        <path start="hive-node"/>
        <path start="hive-node2"/>
    </fork>
    <action name="hive-node">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
           <job-tracker>Jobtracker</job-tracker>
            <name-node>namenode</name-node>
            <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>default</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>HiveForOozie.hql</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to="joining"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
        <action name="hive-node2">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
                <job-tracker>Jobtracker</job-tracker>
                <name-node>namenode</name-node>
                <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
                <configuration>
                   <property>
                        <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                        <value>default</value>
                   </property>
                </configuration>
                <script>Hive2.hql</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to="joining"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
     </action>
    <join name="joining" to="end"/>
     <kill name="fail">
        <message>Hive failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

The second hive action is getting killed because of :-
JA018
org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException$NoNodeException

But when I am running this action as an individual job it is able to go through.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try setting this set hive.support.concurrency=false in both of your queries and try. This error occurs when you try to accuse Zookeeper based lock on tables from oozie.

Comment: You are talking about properties file or hql file?

Comment: Both your hql files.

Comment: It's working, thanks.
But this property will stop hive to run concurrent job and ultimate purpose is to run hive jobs concurrently using fork and join??

PS : I am new in oozie world :P

Comment: Hey donot, I put it in properties file and it worked fine.
When I set in hql file it was showing error in Hive script.
In that case 1st job stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting this set hive.support.concurrency=false in both of your queries and try. This error occurs when you try to get Zookeeper based lock on tables from oozie.
Hive jobs will run in parallel even after setting this property but table Locking capability will not be used.

Please refer this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking) for more details.